# Why putting HTML5 canvas into the background doesn't work?

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, html5-canvas

I am trying to put an HTML5 canvas as the background of my web page. I can't get it to work no matter what I do. Does anyone know how? This is my current attempt:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head> <title> Test </title> </head>

<style>
    #bgcanvas {
        position: fixed;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        z-index = -1;
    }
</style>


<script type="text/javascript">
    function fillCanvas(){
        var bg = document.getElementById("bgcanvas");
        var ctx = bg.getContext("2d");
        ctx.fillStyle = "#00FF00";
        ctx.fillRect(0, 0, 50, 50);

        ctx = document.getElementById("screen").getContext("2d");
        ctx.fillStyle = "#0000FF";
        ctx.fillRect(0, 0, 500, 400);
    }
</script>

<body onload="fillCanvas();">
<center>

    <h1>Test Page</h1>


    <canvas id="screen" width=720 height=480 style="background: black;">
        Your browser sucks. Please upgrade.
    </canvas>

</center>
</body>

<canvas id="bgcanvas" width=100 height=100> </canvas>


</html>
```

Thanks!

Comment: your canvas element is outside the body tag

Comment: z-index can't be negative, and you don't use "=" in CSS.

Comment: Fix the CSS `=` and it will work. But it would be nice to fix the invalid html too... http://jsbin.com/osaxODA/1/edit Also, be aware that scaling the canvas with CSS also scale its contents.

Comment: @Douglas "Boxes may have negative stack levels." http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visuren.html#z-index

Comment: @Ken: ah, yes, you're right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few simple errors here you can adjust to make it work as pointed out in the various comments:

```
#bgcanvas {
    /* ... rest not shown ... */
    /* remove these unless you want the content to scale like an image:
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    */
    z-index: -1; /* change = to :. = is not supported in CSS for properties */
}
```

Move the canvas element *inside* the body tags:

```html
    ...
    <canvas id="bgcanvas" width=100 height=100> </canvas>
</body>
```

Tip: Increase the size to get better quality (you would currently scaling an "image" of 100x100 pixels to about the size of the window which will can give a poor result).

You can alternatively drop the CSS sizing and set the canvas size this way in your script before you draw anything to it:

```js
var bg = document.getElementById("bgcanvas");
bg.width = window.innerWidth;
bg.height = window.innerHeight;
```

Comment: Well this is embarrassing. I did NOT notice I used =, this is so stupid. I'm sorry for wasting everyone's time with such a dumb mistake. P.S. the canvas was outside because I was testing around with moving it through the document. So sorry!

Comment: @Richard it can happen to anyone! :-)